# Filter on MySQL Query without re-querying the database

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table hungry_hippos, and a column named favorite_fruits.

A typical row value for favorite_fruits might be 'apples,oranges,bananas,grapes', and the options of fruits are a fixed/known set.

I'd like to get a COUNT for how many hippos like apples, how many like oranges, etc.

- Can I run a single query, and then filter down the results from that query?
- Do I need to run a database query for each fruit type? In this case, I've got probably 20 kinds of fruit, so I imagine it's not very efficient to hit the DB 20 times.

Comment: `select count(type), type from fruits group by type`, basically

Comment: Please provide a code example that we can begin to review. I suggest doing this in your SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query,this will give you favorite fruit wise count

```
select count(favorite_fruits) as count,favorite_fruits from hungry_hippos group by favorite_fruits
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how it goes. I had it in my head that the **count** function would only work with the value of the entire cell, and not individual values in a CSV such as _apples,bananas,grapes_. I'll report back on the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Because the column with the values is just a csv, counting & grouping on that column seems like, by default, it'll give me a count of each unique combination of values, not each value in the CSV. I'm not sure how to access those values without running a separate query for each one, so I'm biting the bullet and doing it that way.